# Display sub category image in top menu - Magento2

Tags: magento2, category, header, topmenu

I want to display sub-category images in the top menu. I used this but does not show it sub-category images.

1. Create your module
   Create a folder in `app/code/Vendor/NavigationMenu`, where ‘vendor’ is your namespace for your modules.

app/code/Vendor/NavigationMenu/etc/module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_NavigationMenu" setup_version="0.0.1"/></config>
```

**Now the module registration:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Registration file
 *
 * @category  Vendor
 * @package   Vendor\NavigationMenu
 * @author    Your Name <your@name.com>
 * @copyright 2017 Vendor
 * @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_NavigationMenu',
    __DIR__
);
```

2. Rewrite the class `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\TopMenu`.
   Create the `di.xml` to declare the rewriting of the class where the `_getHtml()` method is called:

app/code/Vendor/NavigationMenu/etc/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Vendor\NavigationMenu\Rewrite\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

Now you can create the class that will rewrite the method. Now the following points:

We will add a custom event and an observer to that class. That way we can easily plug whatever we need to the menu.
The actual image addition will be done in the observer.
We had to add some warning suppressions because the `_getHtml()` Magento native function is not compliant to some coding standards

app/code/Vendor/NavigationMenu/Rewrite/Block/Html/Topmenu.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Vendor Project
 * Module Vendor/NavigationMenu
 *
 * @category  Vendor
 * @package   Vendor\NavigationMenu
 * @author    Your Name <your.name@email.com>
 * @copyright 2017 Vendor
 * @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
namespace Vendor\NavigationMenu\Rewrite\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Plugin NavigationMenu
 *
 * @author    Your Name <your.name@email.com>
 * @copyright 2017 Vendor
 */
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    /**
     * Recursively generates top menu html from data that is specified in $menuTree
     *
     * @param Node   $menuTree          menu tree
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass children wrap class
     * @param int    $limit             limit
     * @param array  $colBrakes         column brakes
     * @return string
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD)
     */
    protected function _getHtml(
        Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        $html = parent::_getHtml($menuTree, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colBrakes = []);

        $transportObject = new DataObject(['html' => $html, 'menu_tree' => $menuTree]);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'vendor_topmenu_node_gethtml_after',
            ['menu' => $this->_menu, 'transport' => $transportObject]
        );

        $html = $transportObject->getHtml();

        return $html;
    }
}
```

3. Create an observer triggered by the event
   For this, we’ll need to create the `events.xml` configuration file and assign the class that will handle the event:

app/code/Vendor/NavigationMenu/etc/frontend/events.xml:

app/code/Vendor/NavigationMenu/Observer/AddContentToCategoryTopmenu.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Topmenu catalog observer to add custom additional elements
 *
 * @category  Vendor
 * @package   Vendor\NavigationMenu
 * @author    Your Name <your.name@email.com>
 * @copyright 2017 Vendor
 * @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
namespace Vendor\NavigationMenu\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class AddFirstCategoryImageToTopmenu
 * @package Vendor\NavigationMenu
 */
class AddContentToCategoryTopmenu implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * AddFirstCategoryImageToTopmenu constructor.
     *
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository repository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer Observer object
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $html      = $transport->getHtml();
        $menuTree  = $transport->getMenuTree();

        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $menuId = $menuTree->getId();

        if ($childLevel == 1 && $this->isCategory($menuId)) {
            $html .= '<li class="category_image" style=""><img src="'.$this->getCategoryImage($menuId).'"/></li>';
        }

        $transport->setHtml($html);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the category image for the corresponding child
     *
     * @param string $categoryId Category composed ID
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getCategoryImage($categoryId)
    {
        $categoryIdElements = explode('-', $categoryId);
        $category           = $this->categoryRepository->get(end($categoryIdElements));
        $categoryName       = $category->getImageUrl();

        return $categoryName;
    }

    /**
     * Check if current menu element corresponds to a category
     *
     * @param string $menuId Menu element composed ID
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function isCategory($menuId)
    {
        $menuId = explode('-', $menuId);

        return 'category' == array_shift($menuId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? If so what was the solution?